c++20 how to use concepts to check for overloaded operators
I'm currently struggeling to make my concept check for overloaded operators.
I managed to check for the "normal" <=> operator but I'm failing to check for the <=> operator which uses a std::shared_ptr and compares it with T
#include <compare>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <concepts>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
concept Sortable_T = requires(T a, T b)
{
  { a <=> b } -> std::same_as<std::strong_ordering>;
  { a <=> std::shared_ptr(b) } -> std::same_as<std::strong_ordering>; //< this restraint is causing the problem
};

template<Sortable_T Element_T>
class SortableList
{
  public:
  //some other stuff goes first...
  
  //list is actually private but to keep things simple we make it public here
  std::list<Element_T> m_ls;
};

class MySortableElement
{
public:


  auto operator<=>(const MySortableElement& rhs) const;


  auto operator<=>(const std::shared_ptr<MySortableElement> rhs) const;
};


inline auto MySortableElement::operator<=>(const MySortableElement& rhs) const
{
  //just a dummy
  throw std::runtime_error("not implemented");
}

inline auto MySortableElement::operator<=>(const std::shared_ptr<MySortableElement> rhs) const
{
  //just a dummy
  throw std::runtime_error("not implemented");
}

Now if i invoke my class using
SortableList<MySortableElement> ls;

I'm getting an error that my concept is not satisfied.
Do you know what I'm missing here?
Godbolt Link: https://godbolt.org/z/c5nW71j7P
thx guys :)

std::shared_ptr(b) doesn't look right. Perhaps you mean std::shared_ptr<T>{}?

MySortableElement::operator<=> have return type void because there's no return statement. Is the repro oversimplified?

" I managed to check for the "normal" <=> operator" not with the shown code. Though, no problem, the code is complete and consistent with the godbolt link

First error is this:
<source>(15): note: the concept 'Sortable_T<MySortableElement>' evaluated to false
<source>(11): note: the concept 'std::same_as<void,std::strong_ordering>' evaluated to false
C:/data/msvc/14.39.33321-Pre/include\concepts(35): note: 'void' and 'std::strong_ordering' are different types

Your dummy implementations of operator<=> are too dummy. There is no return, so compiler deduces void as return type. That's part of the reason why I don't like the Almost Always Auto approach.
Fix this by stating return type explicitly and/or implementing the operators in a way the compiler can deduce return type:
inline std::strong_ordering MySortableElement::operator<=>(const MySortableElement& rhs) const
{
  //just a dummy
  throw std::runtime_error("not implemented");
}


Then we see this error:
<source>(12): note: cannot deduce template arguments for 'std::shared_ptr'

std::shared_ptr cannot be created from an object. It's constructor would take a pointer to an object. But that constructor itself is a template, so it cannot deduce type of std::shared_ptr - you have to provide that explicitly.
  { a <=> std::shared_ptr<T>(&b) } -> std::same_as<std::strong_ordering>;

But the simpler option would be to just provide an object of this kind in the context of concept:
template<typename T>
concept Sortable_T = requires(T a, T b, std::shared_ptr<T> sptr)
{
  { a <=> b } -> std::same_as<std::strong_ordering>;
  { a <=> sptr } -> std::same_as<std::strong_ordering>;
};


T b can even be dropped, and just use a <=> a.

Two issues in the code. You let the return type be deduced, but there is no return, hence it gets deduced as void. Further, I had to change a <=> std::shared_ptr(b) because shared_ptr constructor does not do CTAD.
This compiles:
#include <compare>
#include <list>
#include <memory>
#include <concepts>
#include <stdexcept>

template<typename T>
concept Sortable_T = requires(T a, T b)
{
  { a <=> b } -> std::same_as<std::strong_ordering>;
  { a <=> std::make_shared<T>(b) } -> std::same_as<std::strong_ordering>;
};

template<Sortable_T Element_T>
class SortableList
{
  public:
  //some other stuff goes first...
  
  //list is actually private but to keep things simple we make it public here
  std::list<Element_T> m_ls;
};

class MySortableElement
{
public:


  std::strong_ordering  operator<=>(const MySortableElement& rhs) const;


  std::strong_ordering  operator<=>(const std::shared_ptr<MySortableElement> rhs) const;
};


inline std::strong_ordering  MySortableElement::operator<=>(const MySortableElement& rhs) const
{
  //just a dummy
  throw std::runtime_error("not implemented");
}

inline std::strong_ordering  MySortableElement::operator<=>(const std::shared_ptr<MySortableElement> rhs) const
{
  //just a dummy
  throw std::runtime_error("not implemented");
}

int main()
{
    SortableList<MySortableElement> ls;
    return 0;
}

Live Demo

"a <=> std::make_shared<T>(b)" It would have required that T were copy-constructible, if std::make_shared is constrained ;-)
